# Changing Cell Colour With Google Sheets API (PHP)

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to change a ranges colour via the Google Sheets API in PHP.

I have done around an hour of researchig. The code below is as far as I've got.

```
$requests = [
      // Change the spreadsheet's title.
      new Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
          'updateSpreadsheetProperties' => [
              'properties' => [
                  'title' => "The Title"
              ],
              'fields' => 'title'
          ],
          'UpdateCellsRequest' => [
              'properties' => [
                  'range' => "Sheet1!A1",
                  'backgroundColor' => "#000"
              ],
              'fields' => ''
          ]
      ])
    ];

    // Add additional requests (operations) ...
    $batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
        'requests' => $requests
    ]);

    $response = $GoogleSheetsAPIHandler->sheets->spreadsheets->batchUpdate("SHEETID", $batchUpdateRequest);

    print_r($response);
```

If I take out this:

```
'UpdateCellsRequest' => [
  'properties' => [
      'range' => "Sheet1!A1",
      'backgroundColor' => "#000"
  ],
  'fields' => ''
]
```

Then the code works to update the sheets title. However, I can't seem to update a ranges colour.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to change the background color of cells using googleapis for php.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- When you want to use the batchUpdate method of Sheets API, please put each request to each element of the array of `requests`.
- I think that the request body of UpdateCellsRequest in your script is not correct.

  - From your question of `I'm trying to change a ranges colour via the Google Sheets API in PHP.`, when you want to change the background color of several cells with one color, I think that RepeatCellRequest might be suitable.

In this answer, I would like to propose a modified script for changing the several cells using one color. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this, please set the sheet ID.

```
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
        'updateSpreadsheetProperties' => [
            'properties' => [
                'title' => "The Title"
            ],
            'fields' => 'title'
        ]
    ]),
    new Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
        'repeatCell' => [
            'cell' => [
                'userEnteredFormat' => [
                    'backgroundColor' => [
                        'red' => 1,
                        'green' => 0,
                        'blue' => 0
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'range' => [
                'sheetId' => $sheetId,  // <--- Please set the sheet ID.
                'startRowIndex' => 0,
                'endRowIndex' => 3,
                'startColumnIndex' => 0,
                'endColumnIndex' => 2
            ],
            'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat'
        ]
    ])
];
```

- When above request body is used for the batchUpdate method of Sheets API, the title of Spreadsheet is changed and the background color of the cells "A1:B3" changed to the red color.
- Wne you want to use UpdateCellsRequest, you can use the following request body. At the following request body, the background colors of cells "A1:B1" are changed to red and green colors, respectively. When UpdateCellsRequest is used, each cell can be updated. About the detail information of UpdateCellsRequest, please check the official document. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)

  ```
    $requests = [
        new Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
            'updateCells' => [
                'rows' => array([
                    'values' => array(
                        ['userEnteredFormat' => [
                            'backgroundColor' => [
                                'red' => 1,
                                'green' => 0,
                                'blue' => 0
                            ]
                        ]],
                        ['userEnteredFormat' => [
                            'backgroundColor' => [
                                'red' => 0,
                                'green' => 1,
                                'blue' => 0
                            ]
                        ]]
                    )
                ]),
                'range' => [
                    'sheetId' => $sheetId,  // <--- Please set the sheet ID.
                    'startRowIndex' => 0,
                    'startColumnIndex' => 0,
                ],
                'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat'
            ]
        ])
    ];
  ```

#### References:

- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)
- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer! :) I've tried the modified script code. I get this error:https://pastebin.com/whDRYqw4

Comment: @Jack Trowbridge Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Although I'm not sure about your current whole script, from your error message, I thought that you might have used the Spreadsheet ID as `$sheetId`. Sheet ID is different from Spreadsheet ID. If my guess was correct, please modify it. You can see the sheet ID at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet_id). If this didn't resolve your current issue, can you provide your whole script for replicating your issue. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hey, yayyy! Yes, it works now :) Do the indexes start at 0? As I'm changing a cell with a row index of 4 in my PHP. Then in my Google Sheet, it's on row 5... It also resets all the other formatting in that cell. Such as boldness, size, alignment, etc... Is there a way to stop that? Or how would I change that formatting too? Would it be under "userEnteredFormat"

Comment: @Jack Trowbridge Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your 2nd question of `Do the indexes start at 0?`, at Google Spreadsheet, when new Spreadsheet is created, the 1st tab has the sheet ID of `0`. It seems that this is the current specification.

Comment: @Jack Trowbridge About your 3rd question of `As I'm changing a cell with a row index of 4 in my PHP. ,,,`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand it. But I would like to support you. So in order to correctly understand about it, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve it?

Comment: Hi there, you speak every good English! I mean when I choose the startRowIndex and endRowIndex, does this start from zero?

Comment: About my other question, maybe it would be better if I reworded it. How would I change the size, weight, alignment of text as well. Not just the background color. Where exactly would I add these in the code?

Comment: @Jack Trowbridge Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. About your additional question of `I mean when I choose the startRowIndex and endRowIndex, does this start from zero?`, unfortunately, I cannot understand it.

Comment: @Jack Trowbridge And about your updated 3rd question, in that case, how about using [TextFormatRun](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#TextFormatRun)? But I think that this is different from your initial question. So when you need the sample script, please post it as new question. By this, it will help users including me answer it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your replies. I have asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64886023/google-sheet-api-change-column-formatting-when-updating-sheet-values